# Why don't I get the correct variables in my timeseries?

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I am trying to do some forecasting in R based on the numbers in a row in a csv datafile. However, after reading in the file, removing the textcolumns, and using the timeseries function I don't get the values from the row, and don't know where it gets it's values from.

[image]

I tried to check the dataset in the environment, and there appears to be 1 observation of 115 variables and clicking on it takes me to the correct data where I have monthly observations of what I'm studying, but clicking on the little blue circle next to the name a list drops down, where for all 115 variables are described as factors with between 45 and 60 levels. When creating the timeseries I tried vectorizing them, but that doesn't work.

```
library(TTR)
library(forecast)

# then read in the dataset
tourism <- read.csv2("tourism.csv")

# extract relevant rows, vectorize them, and create a timeseries for each    of the 3 groups

total <- tourism[3,]
total <- total[-1:-2]
total <- as.numeric(total)

foreig_tot <- tourism[4,]
foreig_tot <- foreig_tot[-1:-2]
foreig_tot <- as.numeric(foreig_tot)

norwegian <- tourism[5,]
norwegian <- norwegian[-1:-2]
norwegian <- as.numeric(norwegian)

total_ts <- ts(total, frequency = 12, start = c(2010,1))
foreig_tot_ts <- ts(foreig_tot, frequency = 12, start = c(2010,1))
norwegian_ts <- ts(norwegian, frequency = 12, start = c(2010,1))
```

When creating the timeseries I should get values around 95 000 to 150 000, but I get values between 20 and 50 ish.

Comment: I guess your data set has factors inside it. Run `sapply(your_data,class)` to verify it. If it is the case, you can not convert it by just `as.numeric()`, you should convert it by `as.numeric(as.character(data))`.  And if you share a sample data by using `dput(your_sample_data)`, it will be easier to understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: In general, please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.